# Deleting and editing a specific node in xml in flex

Tags: flex3, flex4

Vikram Raman

I am developing a small application for blackberry playbook. I am using flash builder burrito SDK, i could retrive data from xml,but i could not edit and delete data in xml.Can anyone send me the example to remove and edit node in xml using flash builder burrito.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Flash Builder is just an IDE. So there is no any difference which IDE you're using to write your ActionScript code to handle XML within your Flex/AIR application.

Second, to deal with XML in ActionScript you have to learn E4X which is special language for dealing with XML. You can learn more from [the official documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_01.html) or from [examples in internet](http://www.flexafterdark.com/docs/ActionScript-XML).

Hope this helps!